# How to lock and Unlock a URL in java

Tags: java, javascript, spring

There is a hyperlink in my webpage, on click of which it navigates to a jsp page. once am in that jsp page i should be able to lock the jsp page where if others access the same jsp page it should show an alert or a warning saying its already in use. when i come out of that jsp page then if others access the URL it should navigate to that page. Any idea how to achieve that in java? Am using spring framework 3.1. it is a web aplication. Can i handle it in javascript?

Comment: what are yo using, did you write a servlet for that `.jsp` page?

Comment: do you see chance of using websocket or comet approch?

Comment: Strange requirement. You should be looking to *solve* that concurrency problem, by removing it, rather than exposing it to the user.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can create a static counter.
2. you can also set a key/value pair on the first request and your code decides to show alert based on the value of the key.

Comment: can we reset the static counter after we navigate out of the jsp?

Comment: For that you can use a session listener event. So, once your browser or the JSP page is closed the system can signal a sessionDestroy Event and in that you can reset the static counter. Here's the link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B15904_01/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm

Answer (score 0):

To make that work you need couple of things:
1. create a static lock, using concurrnet.util library objects
2. when a user get to the jsp, try to lock. if no success - alert, if sucess  - just show the page
3. when suer holding the lock leave the page, unlock, making any subsequent request to compete for the lock again.

Better off, just for security define that there will be only one instance of the servlet created from the JSP. That is a configuration on the web server.